# Restrict Account Creation Access?

Tags: account, permission-sets

I'm trying to restrict access for Account Creation. I'd rather do this with a permission set but I don't think that's possible.

Is there a way to only show the NEW button for XYZ profile?

[image]

We still want people to have the ability to convert Leads but we want to lock down the NEW account creation to a select few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead conversion [requires create and edit permission on Account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=leads_convert.htm&type=5):

> To convert leads: 
>   Create and Edit on leads, accounts, contacts, and opportunities AND Convert Leads

You will not be able to completely remove the ability to create new Accounts while also preserving the ability to convert Leads.

The route that seems most plausible to me would be to write a Validation Rule on Account. Something like

```
AND(ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISBLANK(LeadSource)),
    NOT($Permission.Some_Custom_Permission)
```

where you'd create a new Custom Permission that allows the creation of new Accounts and add it via Profile or Permission Set to those who should be allowed to have that privilege.

Comment: Validation rules on accounts work but it seems like they don't work until the actual Account has been created. So on that Account Creation Page, the user can click Save all day long. It isn't until after the New Account has been created that the Validation Rules start to work. (Unless I'm doing this wrong?)

I also don't have the option to edit, "Account Edit: New Account" as there is no Edit Page Layout option nor does that exist in Accounts>Page Layouts.

Comment: That is correct. The validation rule would go off only at the point the user clicks Save, and will then stop the save operation from completing.

Comment: Ahh mine isn't working like that... It's allowing the user to Save, then after it's saved, then the Validation Rules are working. But it's allowing them to save which is why I'm in this pickle...

Comment: What validation rule did you write?

Comment: AND(ISNEW(), DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) = TODAY(), 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001ixxx', 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e13000001xxxx', 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00ea00000021xxx', 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e13000001Zxxx', 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001ixxx', 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e1B000000jxxx', 
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001Jxxx' 
)

Comment: That rule will *only* be active on initial save (`ISNEW()`), so I'm a little confused about the issue here. It also does not protect lead conversion.

Comment: I have a meeting right now so standby please. (I don't want to be rude and leave you hanging).

Comment: So here's where I'm at (& I might be way off):

AND(ISNEW(),
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001iXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e13000001xXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00ea00000021XXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e13000001ZXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001iXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e1B000000jXXX',
CreatedBy.ProfileId<>'00e30000001JXXX',
OR (CreatedBy.($Permission.Allow_Account_Creation)))

but Check Syntax Error: Field Allow_Account_Creation does not exist. Check spelling.

I created a permission set and named it "Allow Account Creation", API Name "Allow_Account_Creation"

Comment: Also I'm not sure what to put here:  NOT(ISBLANK(LeadSource)),

In LeadSource

Comment: Nvm, we worked it out. I appreciate the help David, this:

AND(ISNEW(),